# How to distribute a simple desktop application in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, desktop

This is my first attempt in hosting one of my Python projects and after reading multiple tutorials, I am confused on which steps are necessary (i.e. writing it into a python package, freezing it as an .exe, etc)? A lot of the tutorials seem to be overkill for what I feel should be an easy task.

Currently, I have two .py files (one for the gui and one for the back-end) and few miscellaneous data files. The program works for Python 2 and 3.

The end goal would be to have a file or package that another person would be able to download from my website that has a desktop icon executable that prompts the gui. The package will need to be able to install a list of requirements (I can do this through a `requirements.txt` file?).

Would anyone know what the "bare bones" structure should be? (i.e. would I need to write it as a package or would freezing it with a req instllation pre-pended to the gui file work?)

Thanks!

Comment: You could simply cram all the code and the libraries into a single `exe` with smth like py2exe.

Comment: @ForceBru By cramming all the libraries, would that mean installing python and pip and then running pip installations of all the packages (i.e. through a requirements.txt or something of that sort?)

Comment: no, py2exe can gather all the necessary libraries installed on your machine and put them into the executable, so you'll be distributing a single `.exe` file that will have the libs inside already. This may bloat the executable, though, but you can do some trickery to strip off everything that isn't used in your code. You should also be aware that distributing libraries alongside your code might cause legal issues, this depends on the library's license.

Comment: Interesting. For some reason I had thought py2exe was a 1-1 program. I guess I'll look more at it and update here with any progress with it. Thanks!!!